# quickstart : ejb-remote-client:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger

Tags: java, maven, logging, jboss

I want to deploy the project of ejb-remote of quickstart on the wildfly to run,the server-side hash run correctlly.Althougn the client could be compiled,it could not be successful when executing the command "mvn exec:exec",anyone can help me please.sorry i cannot upload the pictures

```
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
```

-->
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.quickstarts</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb-remote</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>ejb-remote-client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>${qs.name.prefix} ejb-remote - client</name>
<description>This project demonstrates how to access an EJB from a remote client; this is the client POM file</description>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Include the ejb client jars -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- We depend on the EJB remote business interfaces of this application -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.quickstarts</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-remote-server-side</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>ejb-client</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TODO remove-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-modules</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jboss/jboss-common-client -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <!-- Add the maven exec plug-in to allow us to run a java program
            via maven -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.exec.plugin}</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/exec-working-directory</workingDirectory>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath></classpath>
                    <argument>org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb.remote.client.RemoteEJBClient</argument>
                </arguments>
                <!--<detail>true</detail>-->
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <!-- build standalone exe jar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb.remote.client.RemoteEJBClient</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: From the maven tag, share the pom.xml and its dependency details specifically to org.jboss being use. And do you or not need any properties to set while `exec:exec`?

Comment: Doesn't the property to set while exec:exec exist in the pom.xml of project?In the pom.xml ,there is a tag <plugin>:<executions> blow:<executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

Comment: Please edit and share pom.xml content in the question.

Comment: ok,I have editted again@nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the intentions are with that pom.xml, but it appears to be broken right now.

Quick fix:

1) add dependency on jboss-logging:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

2) change scope of the jboss-modules dependency to compile:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-modules</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```